# Using an old PEAR package on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php, pear

I'm trying to use this package on Laravel 5.1.x.
https://packagist.org/packages/pear/console_table

Doesn't seem to work out of the box because of the naming. 
File name is `Table.php` and class name is `Console_Table`.

I was wondering if anyone has been able to successfully do something like this in the past?

ie. Make an old package work with Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install a package via composer, you have to use the autoloader generated by composer. Using PEAR's `require_once` statements does not work with packagist packages.